# Cannot run webmatrix site

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix

I have created a site with webmatrix. When I try to run it, it says it cannot because it needs admin right to make the connection to port.

I tried to run Webmatrix with admin right it doesn't change anything. What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit hard to understand.  But I assume you are trying to connect to the site externally meaning from a different computer than the one running webMatrix.  If so, there are a couple of things to get right and this post by Vaidy will help you:  [Serving external traffic with WebMatrix](http://blogs.iis.net/vaidyg/archive/2010/07/29/serving-external-traffic-with-webmatrix-beta.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that you need to be sure that the port you want to use not used by any application.

the problem is that many time user want to debug application in VS oR VWD and Webmatix. because they use same port so Webmatix not run because VWD already use them.

well first thing is that try to change the port and run if that's not work then they need to run as administator for doing that:-

select webmatix icon open the propety go to advanced and choose tor run as administration.